# RSS undefined item element

Tags: php, xml, rss

When I try to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php?id=1) my [RSS feed](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php?id=1), I get the following two errors:

```
line 2, column 359: Undefined item element: shopName (36 occurrences) [help]
... /Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=3100539</guid><shopName>ASOS</shopName><photoU ...
                                             ^
line 2, column 384: Undefined item element: photoURL (36 occurrences) [help]
... =3100539</guid><shopName>ASOS</shopName><photoURL>http://images.asos-med ...
```

Any idea why?

Here's the code I used to create the feed:

```
<?php

function scrape($list_url, $shop_name, $photo_location, $photo_url_root, $product_location, $product_url_root, $was_price_location, $now_price_location, $gender, $country)
{
    header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss/>');
    $xml->addAttribute("version", "2.0");
    //$xml->addAttribute("xmlns:atom", "http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php");
    $channel = $xml->addChild("channel");
    $channel->addChild("title", "Shopaholic");
    $channel->addChild("description", "The RSS feed for Shopaholic");
    $channel->addChild("link", "http://www.sebastiansalek.com");

    $html = file_get_contents($list_url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

    if(!empty($html))
    {
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_clear_errors(); // remove errors for yucky html
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

        /* FIND LINK TO PRODUCT PAGE */

        $products = array();

        $row = $xpath->query($product_location);

        /* Create an array containing products */
        if ($row->length > 0)
        {            
            foreach ($row as $location)
            {
                $product_urls[] = $product_url_root . $location->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }

        $imgs = $xpath->query($photo_location);

        /* Create an array containing the image links */
        if ($imgs->length > 0)
        {            
            foreach ($imgs as $img)
            {
                $photo_url[] = $photo_url_root . $img->getAttribute('src');
            }
        }

        $result = array();

        /* Create an associative array containing all the above values */
        foreach ($product_urls as $i => $product_url)
        {
            $result = array(
                'product_url' => $product_url,
                'shop_name' => $shop_name,
                'photo_url' => $photo_url[$i]
            );

            $item = $channel->addChild("item");
            $item->addChild("title", $result['product_url']);
            $item->addChild("guid", $result['product_url']);
            $item->addChild("shopName", $result['shop_name']);
            $item->addChild("photoURL", $result['photo_url']);
            //print_r($result);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "this is empty";
    }
    echo $xml->asXML();
}

/* CONNECT TO DATABASE */

$dbhost = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "xxx";

$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

/* GET FIELDS FROM DATABASE */

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM scrape WHERE id = '$id'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $list_url = $row['list_url'];
    $shop_name = $row['shop_name'];
    $photo_location = $row['photo_location'];
    $photo_url_root = $row['photo_url_root'];
    $product_location = $row['product_location'];
    $product_url_root = $row['product_url_root'];
    $was_price_location - $row['was_price_location'];
    $now_price_location - $row['now_price_location'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];
    $country = $row['country'];
}

scrape($list_url, $shop_name, $photo_location, $photo_url_root, $product_location, $product_url_root, $was_price_location, $now_price_location, $gender, $country);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: is `<shopName>` part of the [RSS standard](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html)?

Comment: Do RSS items have to be?

Comment: The whole point of the RSS standard is so that readers know what elements to expect. While you could probably add all the elements you want, as long as they are valid XML, no reader is going to use them and a validator that is probably expecting tight coupling to the standard will probably throw a warning saying that an unknown/invalid element was found.

Comment: This feed is for my personal use - I'm parsing it using my own jQuery so as long as it can work with the plugin I'm using (which it currently doesn't because of this) then I don't mind. Is there anything that can be done or will I have to settle for standard items?

Comment: You could modify the plugin. Shouldn't be too hard to add a custom field.

Comment: Here's the code for the plugin: https://raw.github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds/master/jquery.feeds.js Would the custom field be added after the line that starts `for ( var i in feedEntries ) {`?